# Finding Greek from the command-line

Tags: text-processing, perl, unicode

How can I use perl on the command-line to print only lines containing
Greek unicode characters?  For example, only the second of the
following lines

```
  hullo, world
  χαῖρε, ὦ κόσμε
```

It should be possible to use `\p{Greek}` rather than the explicit
range (0370-03ff, 1f00-1fff).

Methods without perl are also welcome, but I suspect sed, awk, grep cannot do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could run something along the lines of

```
perl -C -ne '/\p{Greek}/ and print'
```

Answer (score 1):

Which encoding are you using? If it's UTF-8, you can do:

```
perl -CSD -ne 'print if /\p{Greek}/' input_utf8.txt >output_utf8.txt
```

See the [`-C` switch in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-[_number/list_]*).

If it's another encoding, you can use the [`open` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) for more detailed control.

For example, to read and write UTF-16-LE:

```
perl -Mopen=':std,:encoding(UTF-16-LE)' -ne 'print if /\p{Greek}/' input_utf16le.txt >output_utf16le.txt
```

Or, to read a UTF-16-LE file and output in UTF-8:

```
perl -Mopen=':encoding(UTF-16-LE)' -CS -ne 'print if /\p{Greek}/' input_utf16le.txt >output_utf8.txt
```

Or, to read UTF-16-LE and write UTF-16-BE:

```
perl -Mopen=':std,:encoding(UTF-16-BE),IN,:encoding(UTF-16-LE)' -ne 'print if /\p{Greek}/' input_utf16le.txt >output_utf16be.txt
```

On these latter two, note that there is a subtle but important distinction between `perl ... input.txt >output.txt` and `perl ... <input.txt >output.txt`, since the latter reads from `STDIN`, while the former `open`s the file, so it's important to keep in mind which of the streams you're changing the encoding of.